# my new GeoBook1 laptop bought for Linux hangs despite nomodeset

Tags: boot, usb, laptop

Problem: my cheap new burner laptop bought for Linux hangs after I select “try Ubuntu without installing”. I expect it to boot Ubuntu but I get a black (but very slightly lit I.e. ‘on’) screen.

I used Rufus. Changed boot order to USB. It’s UEFI. Turned off secure boot. Tried to edit code in grub 2.02 to nomodeset. Tried MINT and that didn’t even give me grub, came back to Ubuntu. Tried to change tty, whatever that is, using arrow keys and alt. Tried Fn8 in case it’s brightness but not sure that’s my bright key and cheap laptop has no manual. Don’t think it’s brightness because I see grub. Made sure it was plugged to mains.

Me: used to code BASIC in infancy, stopped, competent at Windows and MacOS for work purposes. Can tinker with RaspPi and code small stuff at home in Python. Want to get into Linux.

My rig: Intel Celeron N3350 Dual-core
Operating system    Windows 10 (64-bit)
RAM 2 GB LPDDR3
Internal Memory eMMC 32 GB
Expandable Memory   MicroSD card: Up to 128GB (Sold separately)
Interfaces  USB 3.0 high speed / USB 2.0 / MicroSD card (up to 128GB) / Mini HDMI / Audio port / Microphone
Connections WiFi & Bluetooth 4.0
Camera  0.3MP Front Camera
Bluetooth   Supported
Display Resolution: 1920 x 1080, 11.6” FHD IPS
Battery Life    Approximately 6 hours
Power Supply    Rechargeable lithium polymer battery with
UK Power Adaptor
Weight  1.043kg

Comment: Did you verify your Ubuntu media using the option at the menu.  You didn't say what Ubuntu release you are using, and in some configurations you may need to to press a key to get the menu to show.  It verifies your download was perfect, and write-to-thumb-drive was good.

Comment: I have not checked the media using the option. How would I do that please? It’s so great you got back btw. As for Ubuntu Version... It’s the current version from the Ubuntu site last night. So it’s Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS unless it changed in the last day or so. EDIT: answered question re checking

Comment: I have worked out how to get into Grub again and I have done    ls     It says (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd3).   I guess I’ll read about that and see if folk answer. If not Illl try MINT or something and then maybe a virtual box.

Comment: Please be specific, the latest version I'd take as being Ubuntu 19.04 (2019-April release), not Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (2018-April LTS release).  When you first boot the live menu you should see a menu the allows a validation ("check disk for defects"  on an image I just booted though not 18.04.2), this may help (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) and yes it's the same option to check cd/dvd or a thumb-drive.  If it fails then I'd validate checksum of your downloaded ISO (to see if download or rufus-write failed), if it passed I'd look in your bios/uefi settings...

Comment: My version is definitely 18.04.2 I checked the title of the file. But I think I may have a lead. My files look like the INCORRECT picture on this link. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD    I’ll take it from here. My learning point is that just because you get some ‘Try Ubuntu’ type grub messages your actual Ubuntu OS might not be up and running. I assumed it was a problem with my cheap laptop. So, cheers for now, thanks again.

Comment: I downloaded 19.04 from the official site. I want to check it. And so now I have set up WSL Ubuntu (from cmd not the store) checked the versions of SHA256SUMS and whatnot and am working on learning the directory handling skills to check the download properly from WSL. I am very happy fiddling about like this.

Comment: I got a Linux magazine dvd with Ubuntu 19.04. It works on my 10yo Mac airbook. I bought an external dvd drive. I dvd booted, pressed ‘e’ to change the script to nomodeset. It hanged in a black screen. I looked around and someone else got success by using bios to change their south core to Linux OS selection. I did that and tried again and my computer is now completely borked. Unresponsive. I keep switching it on and off and trying to press ‘esc’ to get into bios. Nada. I even tried to rescue it using an old Windows rescue disk. I feel sad.

Comment: Opened up the back and did a hard reset. Things working again and my South in bios says Microsoft again. Still no Ubuntu but it’s been a journey.